# How does an `arbiter` vote in mongoDb election?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I do understand why we need an arbiter in mongoDb election, ref - [Why do we need an 'arbiter' in MongoDB replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211154/why-do-we-need-an-arbiter-in-mongodb-replication)

But how does an arbiter actually vote since it does not maintain any replicas of the data?

Does it just votes randomly ? Or does it votes based on some metadata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arbiter does not maintain replicas of the data, but it does maintain the replica set configuration document, and it exchanges heartbeats with the other members of the replica set.

This means that the arbiter has all the same information about member health that the other replica set members have, so it can use exactly the same voting criteria as a secondary node.